# Show Custom Boot-Message

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

I would like to show a custom message during boot, or even better the program cmatrix.

I boot with the "quiet" parameter so there are no startup messages, instead I would like to show a custom-message or the output of a program like cmatrix.

Is this even possible?
How could I achieve this with systemd?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about how you boot and where you would  like the message displayed?

Comment: I've provided a little bit more detail, I don't know much about the boot process so if you need more Information please ask a little bit more specific ;-)

Comment: Well, there are programs like [Plymouth](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/plymouth) that you could probably hack... I boot UEFI and it is so quick there wouldn't be time for `cmatrix`: but I could probably add a custom message to gummiboot.

Comment: I'd take a look at what you can do with Plymouth first. This guide should give you a sense. http://joekuan.wordpress.com/2010/08/05/plymouth-create-your-own-splash-screen-with-scrolling-boot-messages/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve the boot animation with the `systemd` but there is something called `plymouth` you can look at this package.

`Plymouth` is an application runs very early in the boot process[Before root file system is mounted].It is designed to work on system with `DRM` modesetting drivers.For the system that doesn't have `DRM` mode,plymouth falls back to text mode.

So, the plymouth will be having the two binaries`plymouthd` and the `plymouth`.`plymouthd` is responsible for showing the splash screen and the session logging.`plymouth` is responsible for controlling the interface to `plymouthd`.In internet you can find a lot of information regarding the plymouth.

**Edit: (Added some more info)**

Plymouth is shipped with some of the default themes or you can customize your own theme by giving a series of images(.gif doesn't work)to a theme script written by you.

There are  2 ways to specify themes to plymouth

1.Passing a parameter to the kernel command line.

2.Specifying the theme in plymouth configuration file.

**So,Yeah,It's a huge topic,You can search in interent for more information on this.**

Comment: Plymouth appears to heavy for me, I use TDM as Display-Manager so I don't want to use something that heavy...maybe I'll find I lighter solution ;-)