# Display boot splash on ramdisk only system

Tags: linux, embedded, ramdisk, bootsplash

I'm working on a kiosk system with the root file system loaded into RAM. One of the requirements is that the boot process output should be completely hidden from the user. I've already managed to set up the system to display a black screen during boot and just the login prompt for a short time when rebooting. Unfortunately this is not enough.

The ideal solution would be some animated splash screen during boot and reboot/halt i.e. the system boots and the user sees an animation until the graphical system (nodm) is up and the same animation is shown when the graphical system is stopped and the machine is shutting down.

The best solution for this seems to be Plymouth which does exactly what i need. But since my root file system resides in the initrd i do not see any way to include Plymouth in this initrd.

I've found some clues about using two initrd images:

http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2009/09/project-plymouth.html

but was not able to achieve a booting system when trying it.

Does anyone know a way to use plymouth like this or any other solution for displaying an animated splash screen during boot and reboot?

The system specs are:

- AMD G-T56N processor
- ATI Radeon HD 6320 graphics
- 4 GB RAM
- System based on Debian 7.6 64 bit (minimal system with nodm and firefox)

Comment: You can get the answer for this question in this link http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152198/70728

Comment: Thank you but the link does not answer my question. It does not talk about a setup where the initrd contains the root file system. The normal way to get plymouth running is by calling `update-initramfs -u` which obviously can not be done this case.